# How do I get review for my first short story?

Tags: short-story, dramatic-writing

I have wrote an initial draft of a short story.This is my first time. How do I get a review for it?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. Are you asking about finding a *beta reader* or an *editor*, someone who will critique your work to help make it better?

Comment: I had great luck with critters.org

Comment: @LaurenIpsum- yes

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you are looking for someone to critique your story, since you say this is your initial draft. I have two suggestions. Look in your area for a writing critique group (meetup.com may list one in your area or check your library bulletin board). The other is to check out scribophile.com -- you will need to critique other people's work first, to earn karma, and then you can post your work for feedback. You will actually learn from  trying to critique other writing, so this is actually a benefit. Good luck.

Comment: I also recommend that you go through your story on your own first, if you haven't already, and give it a sanity check and edits yourself. I don't recommend sending your actual first draft out to anyone. You may not wind up changing much, but that check for sore thumbs will serve you well.